# "По()темному": нужен ли дефис?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "...пришлось искать ночлег, не по-темному же возвращаться!"
Корректор поправила, поставив дефис в слове "по-темному". А у меня возникли сомнения. Нужен ли он тут? Это ж все равно, что "по темноте". Или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если *"по-темному"* — это наречие с суффиксом *-ому-*, то с *по-* пишется через дефис.  Если же *"темный"* — это, например, лес, то дефис не нужен. Всё зависит от контекста, которого здесь недостаточно, хотя наречие здесь смотрится как-то странно, будто *"возвращаться (как?) по-темному"*. Думаю, в таком случае нарушены нормы. Замена на *"по темноте"* тоже какая-то неубедительная, так как предлог неправильно употреблён.

Answer (score 1):

Частица "по" пишется через дефис в тех случаях если наречие имеет такие окончания (или суффиксы, точно не знаю): "-ому", "-ему", "-и". Пример: по-русски, по-зимнему, по-заячьи, по-светлому. Таким образом, Вы правильно написали по-тёмному через дефис.

Comment: Думаю, здесь не всё так просто. Понятно, например, словосочетание "топить (как?) по-черному", но "возвращаться (как?) по-темному" явно не очень звучит.

Comment: Вот именно! Думаю, задающего вопрос смутило именно это. Тут ведь не однозначное наречие!